# Why Digital/Web/Online Manga are still colored in black-and-white format despite not having publised physically?

Tags: manga-production, mangaka

Is it because amateur mangakas respect the tradition?

Comment: A lot of it is because it's a lot more effort to draw _and_ color, instead of having only two colors. Occasionally though, there are full color versions (e.g. Yuuna and the Haunted Hot Springs). Korean webtoons/Chinese manhua generally _do_ have color, but you can usually see the difference in the time it takes for the artist to draw one page